# Does firestore 'orderBy' order geohashes by distance?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geohashing

The more I read on this topic the more I am confused.
I need small clarification.
If I convert my coordinates to geohash like: `c2b2aaa` using some library that can do that.
And in firestore collection documents I have field 
.

```
doc: {... geohash: 'c2b2qdd'}
doc: {... geohash: 'c2b2abd'}
doc: {... geohash: 'c2b2ahd'}
doc: {... geohash: 'c2b2jjd'}

firestore().collection('myCollection').orderBy('geohash', '>=', 'c2b2aaa').limit(100);
```

Will this query return me up to 100 documents sorted by distance from my location '`c2b2aaa`'?
Or I am too naive and think this would work.

Comment: Second one naive.

Comment: You can use geocaches to check if someone is in a certain sector of a map.

Comment: I need to get data from firebase from collection but closer to my coordinates. If in first page I get data that are 50km faraway I can sort in app but again the closest will ve 50km away. Is there possibility to do this somehow?

Comment: Yes, but you need to make a complicated algorithm.

Comment: Well if you want to be precise, if not you can take first 4 chars and search according to just those. The problem is that person who with those 4 first chars will be in the corner of that sector. You will get for example just places according to north-west where he is.

Comment: Here you have library and everything you need to perform on client side to get correct docs according to location using geohashes. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries Or you can convert it to use it in Firebase functions for example.

Comment: @Mises thanks for pointing me I am step further in understanding this. I see the problem about N & NW. I don't need to be precice but just not to get locations from germany if I am in london. I think 3chars are fine for me (156km).
I am thinking to find all neighbors for my location geohash which means 8 more queries and now I am thinking how to avoid this and pack it in single query... any idea? I am avoiding geofire as I need compound queries `all locations around me where status == 8` for example/

Answer (score 0):

For Firestore Data model perspective, what you'll be doing with your sample document structure is possible but your query does have some issue with it. You need to use the `where()` method when comparing values and use the `orderBy()` method on the field you want to sort (you can also sort it ascending or descending). See sample code below:

```
firestore()
.collection('myCollection')
.where('geohash', '>=', 'c2b2aaa')
.orderBy('geohash', '<asc> or <desc>')
.limit(100)
.get()
.then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

For more information on how to sort data from Firestore, you check out [Order and limit data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#web-version-8).

---

Regarding the Geohash, there are related threads that you might want to check to further help you:

- [Ordering Firestore GeoHash query from closest to furthest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56213015/ordering-firestore-geohash-query-from-closest-to-furthest)
- [how to sort data by geohash in firestore v9 and how does querying geohash work](https://how%20to%20sort%20data%20by%20geohash%20in%20firestore%20v9%20and%20how%20does%20querying%20geohash%20work)
- [How can I use a GeoQuery to sort by both location and certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329334/how-can-i-use-a-geoquery-to-sort-by-both-location-and-certain-value-android/55329416#55329416)

I would also recommend you to watch this video regarding [Querying Firebase and Firestore based on geographic location or distance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q)

Comment: You may also want to check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56213015/ordering-firestore-geohash-query-from-closest-to-furthest).

Comment: Nope, it's not possible. He needs to first get to know what queries he needs to perform, then query them all, so he gets documents in range/area. If he wants to sort the result according to distance, he needs to count the distance to every document according to his position.

Comment: @Mises , I just based on the sample document structure provided which contains strings that can be compared and ordered by its field but as I mentioned, there are threads regarding how to properly query  and order data by distance with Geohash.

Comment: Your answer looks confuse. Someone may not understand that you only shows/explain he wrote bad request. Someone may understand that this is an example of requests he needs to perform to get documents in a range.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll just clarify it on my answer.